# MemoryError when scraping film data from IMDB

Tags: python, web-scraping, out-of-memory

I wrote a program to scrape IMDB to save information about the films I have seen. There are about 1500 films in the list. Something is going wrong and I can't figure out what.

This is the code:

```
from __future__ import division
import json
import io
from pprint import pprint
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
import time
import os
import psutil


links = [u'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0354899', u'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1020530', u'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099864', u'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100157', u'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0324216', u'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0054215', u'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0435625', u'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0454841', u'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0450278', u'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1179904']



# relevant part starts here. "Links" is a list of links to IMDB pages

information = [["title", "date", "duration", "rating"]]
for number, link in enumerate(links):
    response = urllib2.urlopen(link)
    html = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    print "\n", link
    print "Percentage completed", number/len(links)
    print "Time elapsed", time.clock() - t0
    try:
        date = soup.find(itemprop="datePublished")["content"]
        title = soup.find(property='og:title')["content"]
        duration = soup.find(itemprop="duration").string.replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "")
        rating = soup.find(itemprop="ratingValue").string
        print date, title, duration, rating
    except KeyError:
        print "There was a problem"
```

This is the MemoryError it throws after a while:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pplsuser/Dropbox/Stupidaggini/IMDBscraper/scraper.py", line 28, in <module>
    html = response.read()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 362, in read
    buf.write(data)
MemoryError: out of memory
```

I am not sure what is happening, and so not sure how to fix it. It seems that the Memory consumption increases constantly. There are many links so maybe something is being saved incrementally and sucks more and more memory, but I can't spot what might be doing that.

Comment: Problem seems to be when reading data from the server. Does it always fail on the same link, and what is the link?

Comment: I am running it again to double check, but I think it fails on different links every time.

Comment: Try using [`requests`](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiyo4S3ucLVAhWDppQKHaaTB04QFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.python-requests.org%2F&usg=AFQjCNFyAH9fsxdKUHgs_F_P-ZQ_-_P1nw) instead of `urllib2`. Code: `soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(link).content, 'lxml')`